# How to scrape a website, login to a user account and avoid to see its user password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, encryption

Im building an application based in Ruby-On-Rails that facilitate users to obtain their information from different websites into one centralized dashboard. To do that, at the beginning the app asks for their login information (user+password) of every website.

Because we are working with sensitive information we have to save the users data encrypted in our database. Afterwards, to login into the users account, we decrypt the password in the database and login to the webpage using his/her info.

We want to avoid to see the user private information at any moment during the web-scraping.**Is there a way to use their information to login into their account and obtain the data that they are looking for, avoiding any chance for us to see their private information ?**

Comment: Please don't take offense, if you need to ask this question, you're probably in over your head. What you're making is pretty much a password manager, or some form of it, and what you are asking about is the key part. Hire a security expert.

Comment: If you insist on doing this yourself, I would approach the problem by using the users password client side to derive a key using PBKDF2 or similar and then encrypt the login information client side with a symmetric algorithm.  You can then reverse the process when the login information is required.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt take it as an offense. The process run synchronously in the server side, therefore the user will never see the passwords again. Decrypting in the client side wouldnt work.